# Make model class from view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In ASP.NET MVC one can create strongly typed Views but suppose if a view has already been made, so would it be possible to derive a model from it?

Like create model from view. A possible scenario would be: a designer makes a view (with forms) and then the developer would create a model from that form

Comment: I've never heard of this, but would be cool if possible. Though I have my doubts.

Comment: Even if you could create some kind of parser to generate a model class, how would you know what data types to assign to the properties?

Comment: @300 baud Since at the end of the day everything is serialized into a string for html output, perhaps the derive tool would just assume all properties to be a string? then after the tool runs the user could edit the data types themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible?  Yes.

You could certainly translate `<input type="text" data-format="int" name="Price" />` into `public int Price { get; set; }`

Devil is in the details though.

Comment: Or if you only allow it for HTML5:
<input type="number" name="rating" min="1" max="10" /> would translate to:  [Range(1, 10)] public int Rating{get; set;}

Comment: Thank you guys. Are there any simple tutorials on this that i can refer to?